# Why does -3^2*(-3)^2 = -81

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

Why does `-3^2*(-3)^2 = -81` ?
Whereas both `-3^2` and `(-3)^2` both equals `9`. I've run the equation in wolfram alpha and it does indeed give the results stated above.

Comment: [No repro for `-3^2 = 9`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-3%5E2). See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382664/32-9-correct-syntax-for-a-negative-number-with-an-exponent

Comment: how does -3*-3 = -9? What have i forgotten/missed in school? thanks for the link, post it as an answer and ill give you the correct answer

Comment: Unfortunately I will not be posting an answer as I believe this question is off-topic for SO. From my understanding, this is more of a math question than a programming question. Not only that, but part of it is also not reproducible. I'm glad to have helped but I also want to make sure SO functions as it should :)

Comment: Start by looking at WolframAlpha's readback of the input to see if the properly-formatted math symbolism reflects the intent of the expression. If it does, then this question belongs on Math.SE because it's about math conventions regarding order of operations. If the symbolism is _different_ than you expected, then this could be a valid SE question about syntax used in ASCII representations of math expressions.

Comment: sry about being on the wrong site and thanks for leading me to the answer anyway :)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs This is completely a programming question. `-3^9` is not math, it's an expression from a programming language, and the question is whether this expression represents the mathematical expression `(-3)⁹` or `- 3⁹`.

Answer (score 2):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

> The order of operations, which is used throughout mathematics,
> science, technology and many computer programming languages, is
> expressed here:
>
> 1. exponentiation and root extraction
> 2. multiplication and division
> 3. addition and subtraction

So `1 + 2 × 3 = 7`

and `0 - 3^2 = -9`

See specifically
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Unary_minus_sign

> There are differing conventions concerning the unary operator −
> (usually read "minus"). In written or printed mathematics, the
> expression `−3^2` is interpreted to mean `−(3^2) = −9`.
>
> In some applications and programming languages, notably Microsoft
> Excel, PlanMaker (and other spreadsheet applications) and the
> programming language bc, unary operators have a higher priority than
> binary operators, that is, the unary minus has higher precedence than
> exponentiation, so in those languages `−3^2` will be interpreted as
> `(−3)^2 = 9`.

Answer (score 1):

From the link from a comment from FheFungusAmongsUs

−x^2, in every mathematical context I have seen, always means −(x^2). So −3^2=−9.

[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382664/32-9-correct-syntax-for-a-negative-number-with-an-exponent)